# Change of state in another component

Tags: reactjs

How to solve the problem attached in the drawing?

I am talking about the best possible way of getting used without using redux.

When a button is pressed in a nested component, something has to change in another (it does not inherit from itself)

For example, in one component I choose the element and in the other I want to display details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a shared parent hold the state you want to change and pass to the first component while sending the onClick function to the other. Then, when one component changes the state through the onClick function, the changed prop will be passed on to the second component.

Answer (score -1):

You should not change the state from one component via another component:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

> `props` get passed to the component (similar to function parameters)
>   whereas `state` is managed within the component (similar to variables
>   declared within a function).

For "States" between components, you should use props from the store, via `react-redux`

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I will suggest you to look into [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in react.

Now, how you'll do it: (just a pseudo example)

ParentComponent

```
onClick={this.onClick} stateProps={this.state.stateProps}

onClick() {
  this.setState()
}
```

ComponentA

```
onClick={props.onClick}
```

ComponentB

```
console.log(props.stateProps)
```

The component will be used like: (again just a pseudo example)

```
<ParentComponent onClick={this.onClick} stateProps={this.state.stateProps}>
  <ComponentA onClick={props.onClick} />
  <ComponentB stateProps={props.stateProps} />
</ParentComponent>
```